# How do I get Ubuntu 16.04 to see my Android phone storage

Tags: android

I used to be able to connect my Android smartphone by USB cable to my Laptop running Ubuntu. Before 16.04 when I did so the phone prompted me on how to "use USB for" and I would select Transfer files (MTP). Icons for the phone internal storage and SD card would appear in the Ubuntu Launcher and I could access the internal storage and SD card from there. 
I now run Ubuntu 16.04 and Android 6 and from advice on askubuntu I have now installed gMTP which will connect to the phone internal storage or SD card.
However I have found gMTP very very slow and unreliable.
Is there another way I can see my phone storage please?

Comment: Actually a new install of 16.04 that I have just done in another partition sees my Android storage perfectly well. So I think that some update to 16.04 or my installation of various apps including ppa ones may be to blame.